# Phrase translation

Tags: translation

I just want to ask you if i have translated my phrase correctly to German:

Eng: I wish I had more time.

Deu: Ich wünche mehr zeit hatten.

I just want to ask you if the German version would fit into a conversation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is no german sentense at all...

Comment: Even Google Translate has no problem with your sentence: https://translate.google.de/#en/de/I%20wish%20I%20had%20more%20time.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is “Ich wünschte ich hätte mehr Zeit.” (as Devon also mentioned, referring to your sentence). Note that nouns *always* start with a capital letter in German.

time = **Z**eit

Comment: A comma is missing here: Ich wünschte, ich hätte mehr Zeit. In German when there is a _Nebensatz_ a comma is mandatory.